# How can I assert the message of the anticipated exception using Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

It's quite obvious to me that there must be a way to compare the message of the anticipated exception to an expected constant that should be provided with the [ExpectedException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.expectedexceptionattribute.aspx) attribute. Unfortunately there is nothing like that. Am I missing anything?

Comment: You have to create your own ExpectedException Attribueb (it's very simple). See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944774/in-mstest-how-can-i-verify-exact-error-message-using-expectedexceptiontypeof/9152420#9152420)

Answer (score 1):

No, you are not missing anything.  You'll have to try/catch the exception and examine it yourself.

You may want to consider using a better unit test framework, such as xUnit.net, which provides a better support for asserting exceptions.

Note, using ExpectedException can be problematic (see the note about this in "Lessons Learned" at http://xunit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WhyDidWeBuildXunit)

Comment: They just blindly copied NUnit, with all its failings. xUnit.net attempts to fix all that.  We're still using mstest, but I just wrote my own version of `Assert.Throws<>`, and I'm pretty happy.